# Conditional Formating Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet...  I need to highlight the rows where the difference between two columns is equal to or greater than 0.1%. In the columns that I want to check for differences some are represented in positive and some in negative %. I hope my question made sense. Thank You In Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take the absolute value when dealing with mixed negatives and positives:

```
=ABS(($B1-$A1)/$A1)>= 0.01
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I did greater than or equal to 1%, so just change 0.01 to 0.001 if wanting 0.1%.